# How to show __/__/____ in textbox at load time for dd/mm/yyyy and replace __/__/____ with date?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

How to use forward slashes for date in dd/mm/yyyy format in textbox?
Code which I have tried is -

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Enter valid Date" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"             
        ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(/)(0[13578]|1[02])(/)                                                                                                                                                            ((19|20)\d\d))|
       ((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(/)(0[13456789]|1[012])(/)((19|20)\d\d))|
       ((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])(/)02(/)((19|20)\d)\d))|
       (29(/)02(/)((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$">
       </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: A function to validate the date is much simpler than that regular expression: `function validateDMY(s) {s = s.split(/\D/); return (new Date(s[2], --s[1], s[0])).getMonth() == s[1];}`.

Answer (score 0):

use HTML5 placeholders.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator placeholder="__\/__\/___" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Enter valid Date" ControlToValidate="TextBox3"             
    ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(/)(0[13578]|1[02])(/)                                                                                                                                                            ((19|20)\d\d))|
   ((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(/)(0[13456789]|1[012])(/)((19|20)\d\d))|
   ((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])(/)02(/)((19|20)\d)\d))|
   (29(/)02(/)((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$">
   </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

You can use `placeholder`. It's a HTML5 attribute that displays a placeholder value when the input is empty.

Comment: Far better than a placeholder is a tip on the screen like: "dd/mm/yyyy" adjacent to the control that doesn't disappear when the control gets focus or when users start to type. Also, a hint of `__/__/____` doesn't give much idea of the required format.

Comment: But Placeholder gets deleted when we type in the textbox, I want fixed __/__/____ in the textbox and user will only type the date for eg. for 01/02/2015, user will only type 01022015 in the textbox. As user will write 01  (i.e. day) then cursor should set to the place where user will write 02 (i.e. month).